# How to write multiple files with nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building my own code editor with 3 textareas: html, css and javascript. This code editor will save the data of the textareas to single files separately.

Using express and nodejs, I manage to save just the data from the html textarea.

```
function htmlFile(file, data, response) {
var name = "files/" + file + ".html";
var content = data;
fs.writeFile(name, content, function (err) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
    response.send(err);
} else {
    response.send(' index.html file saved at: ' + name + ') Notes: ');
}
});
};

// static directory
app.use(express.static('static'))

// Home Page: index.html
app.get('/', (req, res) =>  {
res.sendFile('./static/index.html');
});

// create page
app.get('/page', (req, res) =>  {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/static/index.html');
});

app.post('/page', function (req, response) {
var file = req.body.file;
var content = req.body.myPage;
htmlFile(file, content, response);
});
```

So, my question is:

Is it possible to save multiple files from different textareas?

Main goal is to save the content of the css textarea as style.css and the content of the javascript textarea as scripts.js

Thank you.

Comment: You are POSTing `file` and `content` to the `/page` route and then saving the file using the `htmlFile()` function. You have to POST contents of all three textarea elements and presumably the corresponding filenames in similar fashion and then save them in the same way you are saving the HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your webpage, put all your text area elements in a `<form>` and then make sure each textarea has `name` attribute. Then on submitting, your `POST` request will contain content of each textarea which you can access in Express by using `req.body.nameAttributeOfRespectiveTextArea`. Save content as per your needs then!

Comment: Thanks jsgrewal12. I'm just wondering how I'm gonna writeFile 3 files in the same function or I need to create 3 different functions to do it. Is there a way to have a writeFile stream to do it? Thank you

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand what you mean. Can you please rephrase. Thanks

Comment: Hi jsgrewal12, the way you described works fine. I just created 3 writeFiles function to save 3 different files, but your answer is the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @ffas I am glad it helped. If you liked the answer, please upvote it so that other members from the community too can get help from it.